# How can I get iAd to fly in to prevent white box?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iad

I am using a shared method to have iAD appear across three view controllers and using the App Delegate. The issue I am having is that when ads do not appear it is forming the white box. I know Apple will not approve the app if the white box appears. What can I code to have the ad start off screen and have it fly in when an ad is present and when an ad is not present, have it fly off.

I assume I would change this on all three views.

Here is the code for each .m

```
- (AppDelegate *) appdelegate {
return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 }

 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 _UIiAD = [[self appdelegate] UIiAD];
_UIiAD.delegate = self;

 [_UIiAD setFrame:CGRectMake(100,700,320,50)];
 [self.view addSubview:_UIiAD];
 }



 -(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner{


NSLog(@"ads loaded");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[_UIiAD setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error{
NSLog(@"ads not loaded");
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[_UIiAD setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

If it helps, ads are being place on the bottom of a landscape mode iPad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer supplies above. It now works for shared screen iad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Write this in your .m file:

```
-(void)AD_init
{
_adBanner = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 50)];
_adBanner.delegate = self;

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
if (!_bannerIsVisible)
{
    if (_adBanner.superview == nil)
    {
        [self.view addSubview:_adBanner];
    }

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = YES;
}
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"Failed to retrieve ad data");

if (_bannerIsVisible)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

    banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    _bannerIsVisible = NO;
}
}
```

And in your .h file :

```
  BOOL _bannerIsVisible;
ADBannerView *_adBanner;
```